# SlowCheetah not transforming web.config on build

Tags: msbuild, slowcheetah

I installed the SlowCheetah package via nuget and added transform files for my web.config based on Build config. 
However, on building, the web.config does not get transformed. I checked my project file and did see entries for SlowCheetah PropertyGroup and Import elements. I dont see a target for transformation in the project file.
If I add an app.config, the app.config file does get transformed.
It is my understanding that installing the SlowCheetah package should automatically add the web.config transform target to the MSBuild file for the project. I can add it manually but I thought SlowCheetah does it out of the box.
Am I missing something. Please do let me know.
My requirement is that my web.config file should get transformed based on build configuration and the transformed web.config file should be located in the output directory.
Thanks and appreciate all help.

Answer (score 19):

Visual Studio is doing Transformation only when you deploy your project by using the publish functionality. To do it when you do the build you need to tweak your MSBuild script. The complete solution is [here](http://sebnilsson.com/a5410281/asp-net-transform-web-config-with-debug-release-on-build/). Here the essentials:

> Files in project Create a file named Web.Base.config, besides the
>   existing Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config. This file will be
>   the equivalent to your old Web.config, as it will be the base for the
>   tranformation. You will end up with these files:
>
> Web.config, Web.Base.config, Web.Debug.config, Web.Release.config, and
>   Web.config. Add the following configuration to the bottom of your
>   .csproj-file, just before the closing -tag:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <TransformXml Source="Web.Base.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.config" />
</Target>
```

> UPDATE: From a reminder in the comments I realized that I also have a
>   problem with Visual Studio transforming the XML twice, when Publishing
>   a project. The solution to this is to add a Condition to the
>   Target-tag like this:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(PublishProfileName)' == '' And '$(WebPublishProfileFile)' == ''">
```

Comment: Regarding the solution, for Visual Studio 2013, you don't need the <Import> since the <XmlTransform> task is already imported.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.

Comment: yas yas yas yas
!

Comment: The question was about SlowCheetah, which is an extension+NuGet package that should do this for you.

Comment: One drawback to consider: As Jacob Viau [points out](https://github.com/Microsoft/slow-cheetah/issues/64#issuecomment-314595565), this will break NuGet package installations that modify `Web.config`.

Comment: I'm getting the page cannot be run in debug mode because debuggging is not enable in the Web.config file

Comment: The question is about SlowCheetah.

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate on Philipp's answer I have found a possible simpler solution:
No need for a Web.Base.Config and no problems with overwriting your web.config which causes problems in Source Control.

> BeforeBuild: You make the destination your TargetDir en TargetFileName.
>
> AfterBuild: You copy this to your published websites after the build is done.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName).config" />
</Target>
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Dev' Or '$(Configuration)' == 'Test' Or '$(Configuration)' == 'Prod'">
    <Delete Files="$(TargetDir)_PublishedWebsites\$(ProjectName)\Web.config" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName).config" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)_PublishedWebsites\$(ProjectName)\Web.config" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why the build wouldn't replace the config file that was copied there before the build? Because I can't get this to work, and I think it's because the file is overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the "copy to output directory" property of your transform files to "Do not copy" ?
Please check also your project file.

In your project file the following entries should be added (depending the version you installed , in this case 2.5.7):

```
<PropertyGroup Label="SlowCheetah">
<SlowCheetah_EnableImportFromNuGet Condition=" '$(SC_EnableImportFromNuGet)'=='' ">true</SlowCheetah_EnableImportFromNuGet>
<SlowCheetah_NuGetImportPath Condition=" '$(SlowCheetah_NuGetImportPath)'=='' ">$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath( $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\packages\SlowCheetah.2.5.7\tools\SlowCheetah.Transforms.targets ))</SlowCheetah_NuGetImportPath>
<SlowCheetahTargets Condition=" '$(SlowCheetah_EnableImportFromNuGet)'=='true' and Exists('$(SlowCheetah_NuGetImportPath)') ">$(SlowCheetah_NuGetImportPath)</SlowCheetahTargets>
```

```
<Import Project="$(SlowCheetahTargets)" Condition="Exists('$(SlowCheetahTargets)')" Label="SlowCheetah" />
```

Comment: For anyone watching, this is 100% incorrect for a current version of SlowCheetah.